# Zend get value from textbox and add it into search url

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, search

I have question,this is the following code.

```
<form action="" method="post" id="search">
        <div class="row collapse">
        <div class="ten columns mobile-three">
        <input type="text" size="25" name="search" value="<?php echo $this->search ?>"/>
        </div>
        <div class="two columns mobile-three">
        <input type="submit" name="/search/index/keyword/" value="Search"; ?>" class="button   expand postfix" id="search_button"/> 
        </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

when I click the submit button,the url should be
from `id/` to `id/search/index/keyword/(here's the search key)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<form action="" method="post" id="search" name="search" onsubmit="submitForm();">
        <div class="row collapse">
        <div class="ten columns mobile-three">
        <input type="text" size="25" name="search" id="search_value" value="<?php echo $this->search ?>"/>
        </div>
        <div class="two columns mobile-three">
        <input type="hidden" value="/search/index/keyword/" id="search_url"/> 
        <input type="submit" name="search" class="button   expand postfix" id="search_button"/> 
        </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

JS

```
<script>
    function submitForm() 
    {
        var search_button = document.getElementById('search_url').value;
        var search_text = document.getElementById('search_value').value;
        document.searchForm.action = search_button + '/' + search_text;
        document.searchForm.submit();
        return false;
    }

</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    // add action code here
}

?>
```

Comment: never thought it would be using javascript,I'm not good enough at javascript.but this one is works I just have to change the url.thank you

Comment: Should not the form name="searchForm" as document.searchForm is used in JS

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a server-side language for that. Make a process page (unless you're familiar with AJAX), get the values by $_POST and make the process page redirect.

I'm pretty sure that it's possible using JavaScript as well, but I'm really bad at it so don't count on my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS to accomplish your goal.

1) make a function that runs when user clicks submit button.

2) function grabs the word from search box.

3) function changes the "action" attribute on the form element

4) form is submitted